# Why do I get 404 not found error when trying to load my just-deployed Source Bundle in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

## Overview

I have a very simple CodePipeline that deploys new versions of an application to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. If I run the pipeline, it works and the application is deployed without errors. But if I then navigate to view the "Application versions" for my application, and click the link for the "Source Bundle" for the just-now-deployed version at the top of the list, I'm just shown a generic AWS 404 not found page. If I click on ANY source bundle links, I see the same error.

What in the world is happening?

## Some context

The CodePipeline successfully uploads the build artifacts to the designated artifact bucket. Those artifacts are all still there. The links from the Application Versions page don't seem to be resolving correctly.

I have a Lifecycle defined for my Application Versions to limit to the last 50 versions, and to retain the source bundles in S3. The source bundles are in the bucket mentioned in the previous paragraph, designated for the artifacts, but there are no source bundles in the elasticbeanstalk bucket. This has puzzled more than one AWS Support technicians already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was using the new fancy redesigned beta console. The link in the old console works perfectly.